# Java methods | Passing values

Tags: java, methods

I am a beginner in Java and my professor wants us to create a program that involves some math. The thing is that he wants the calculations in a separate method. Can someone please help me. The program will not run the result for some reason. I tried looking around this website and could not find the answer. Here is the code below:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class forFun {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double x, y, z;
        String xVal, yVal, zVal;
        xVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first integer: ");
        yVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second integer: ");
        zVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter third integer: ");

        x = Double.parseDouble(xVal);
        y = Double.parseDouble(yVal);
        z = Double.parseDouble(zVal);

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void sumOfStocks(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        double result = x * y * z;

        System.out.println("The product of the integers is: " + result);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You NEVER call the method.

Comment: Also the method shouldn't be void, shouldn't print out anything or exit. Instead, it should return the double result value, and let the main program print it out. Regardless, the solution to this is to read any tutorial on Java methods. Any.

Comment: Start with: [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), then [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) and finally [Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Comment: As Hovercraft Full Of Eels said, you never called the method. You should add `sumOfStocks(x, y, z);` just before the `System.exit(0);` to make that method call.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of how the code should be

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class forFun {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double x, y, z;
    String xVal, yVal, zVal;
    xVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first integer: ");
    yVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second integer: ");
    zVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter third integer: ");

    x = Double.parseDouble(xVal);
    y = Double.parseDouble(yVal);
    z = Double.parseDouble(zVal);
    double result = sumOfStocks(x, y, z);
    System.out.println("The result is %d", result);
    System.exit(0);
}

public static double sumOfStocks(double x, double y, double z)
{
    double result = x * y * z;
    return result;

}
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake, instead of System.out.println, it should be System.out.printf